# Why does Json.Net not properly serialize byte[] when it is dictionary key?

Tags: c#, json.net

I tried to serialize a `Dictionary<byte[] , int>` using Json.Net, however it convert all the byte[] as "System.Byte[]". But if I reverse the type of key and value in the Dictionary. It works very well using Base64 to serialize byte[]. I am wondering why it does not work for byte[] key? What's the reasoning behind?

Below is the code I tried:

```
        var dict1 = new Dictionary<byte[], int>
        {
            [Guid.NewGuid().ToByteArray()] = 1,
            [Guid.NewGuid().ToByteArray()] = 2
        };
        string dict1Json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dict1);
        Console.WriteLine(dict1Json);
        //{ "System.Byte[]":1,"System.Byte[]":2}

        var dict2 = new Dictionary<int, byte[]>
        {
            [1] = Guid.NewGuid().ToByteArray(),
            [2] = Guid.NewGuid().ToByteArray()
        };
        var dict2Json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dict2);
        Console.WriteLine(dict2Json);
        //{ "1":"JgrYtch/6Eq3Nyoe8pnnpg==","2":"KbfVMzjz20yCYvc9FiVKKA=="}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The author of Json.NET [answered](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/69#issuecomment-16144970) that on GitHub:

> That's expected behavior. The key has to be a string. If Json.NET can't find any TypeConverter then it will call ToString.

Json.NET isn't finding a type converter, so it calls `ToString` on the key. `ToString` by default returns the name of the type, which in this case is "System.Byte[]".

Values of dictionaries have different behavior. The run through conversion logic, which is why they can be properly serialized as values since there is a `BinaryConverter`. Why this is is only known to the author, but I suspect it is performance related as well as a little-needed feature.

You are better off not using a collection as a key in your object model. If your keys are GUIDs, then just use `System.Guid` or convert the Guid to a string.